# In Romans 8 how do we understand the use of the definite article with "flesh", from grammar not received theology?

Tags: spirit, flesh

From the grammar how should we understand the use of the definite article in Romans 8 for "the flesh"? I've read that definite article before spirit is usually understood as God's Spirit, and that no definite article before a noun tends to make it qualitative, somewhat like an adjective.

However, Romans 8:1-17 goes back and forth between definite article and indefinite article for flesh. So:

1. Why the use of the definite article?
2. Are we meant to understand those differently?
3. If not, might that imply that we capitalise "the spirit" a bit too easily in this passage as "the flesh" and "the spirit" is usually used in parallel contrast here?

Answer (score 0):

The rules surrounding the definite article in Greek are quite different from those in English and for more involved that what the OP has "read".  Indeed, advanced grammarians like Daniel Wallace in his famous tome, "Greek Grammar Beyond the Basics" spends a large section of the book devoted to the Greek article.  I do not intend to reproduce that here.

Suffice to say here, that in this context, the article performs the anaphoric function - it refers the reader's mind back to the previous instance of the word which did not have the article.  Let me list them out according to the text of UBS5/NA28.  I will use my own literal translation throughout.  The Greek word for "flesh" is "sarx".

- **Rom 4:1** - κατὰ σάρκα (no article) "according to flesh".  This text is pivotal and Paul uses this term "sarx" to mean the sinful human nature.
- Rom 6:19 - τὴν ἀσθένειαν **τῆς** σαρκὸς ὑμῶν "the weakness of the flesh of you [this refers back to Rom 4:1]
- Rom 7:5 - ἐν **τῇ** σαρκί "in the flesh" [this refers back to Rom 4:1]
- Rom 7:18 - ἐν **τῇ** σαρκί "in the flesh" [this refers back to Rom 4:1]
- Rom 7:25 - **τῇ** δὲ σαρκί "but the flesh" [this refers back to Rom 4:1]
- Rom 8:3a - διὰ **τῆς** σαρκός "through the flesh" [this refers back to Rom 4:1]

**Next section:**

- Rom 8:3b - ἐν ὁμοιώματι σαρκὸς (no article) Paul now uses sarx to mean "human" more generally as distinct from "sinful human nature"
- Rom 8:3c - ἐν τῇ σαρκί "in the flesh" [this refers back to Rom 8:3a]
- Rom 8:4 - **τοῖς** μὴ κατὰ σάρκα "not according to the flesh" [this refers back to Rom 8:3a]

Rom 8:5-8 begins a pair of quintessential Hebrew contrasting (ie, antithetical) parallelisms as follows to contrast humanity from the Spirit-led life; but all these have the article and refer to Rom 8:5a.

**Rom 8:5**

- **A:** Those being according to flesh mind the things of **the** flesh
- **B:** but those according to Spirit, the things of the Spirit

**Rom 8:6**

- **A:** The mind of **the** flesh [is] death
- **B:** but the mind of the Spirit [is] life and peace V7: because the mind of **the** flesh is hostility toward God; for it is not subject to the Law of God, for not even can it be.

**Conclusion**

- Rom 8:8, 9 - Now, those being in flesh cannot please God.  But you are not in flesh but in Spirit if indeed [the] Spirit of God dwells in you. ...

The last three instances in this chapter are all found in Rom 8:12, 13 and all refer back to Rom 8:8.  Rom 8:12, 13 says

> So then brothers, we are debtors, not to **the** flesh to live
> according to **the** flesh; for if you live according to [the] flesh you
> are about to die; but if you live by Spirit, you will put to death the
> deeds of the body.

Note that here, the duplication of "according to" essentially duplicated the article (or more precisely the article still governs the second instance).  These both refer back to Rom 8:5.

Comment: Thank you. That's rather helpful as applied to flesh/ σάρκα. And the anaphoric mechanism works back as far as chapter 4? σάρκα is even in chapter 1, I note, but perhaps is not referred to because it's used in a different context? As to spirit/ πνευμα, it would seem that context in Romans is far more difficult an indicator since it is used both for one's own spirit and God's Spirit and perhaps as the aspect of spirit / spiritual.

Comment: @BruceW - agreed